# Search, java I have no err

Tags: javascript

I wrote a phonebook app that has three functions: add, delete and search.
I want the content to be saved in the presentation after filling the input, and at the same time the content of my presentation will be displayed after saving using the `showrecords` function.
In the search field, I want to search among the added contacts and if a result is found, it will show in the console
In the delete function, I also want to delete any contact that I did not want
But unfortunately none of my functions work and I do not receive any errors and I do not know where the problem comes from, please help

```js
 let AddBtn = document.getElementById('Add');
    let search = document.getElementById('search');
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    let phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    let selectInputsearch = document.getElementById("search");
    let buttonsearch = document.getElementById("btnsearch");
    let addBookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook');
    AddBtn.addEventListener("click", addToBook);
    addBookDiv.addEventListener("click", removeEntry);
    buttonsearch.addEventListener("click", searchContact);

    this.PhoneBookRecord = function(name, phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    function addToBook() {
        this.records = [];
        let isNull = name.value != '' && phone.value != '';
        if (isNull) {
            let obj = new PhoneBookRecord(name.value, phone.value);
            records.push(obj);
            showrecords();
        }
    }

    function searchContact() {
        this.records = [];
        const result = this.records.find((name) => name === selectInputsearch.value);
        if (!result === undefined) {
            console.log(result)
        } else {
            console.log("Contact not found")
        }
    }

    function removeEntry(item) {
        this.records = [];
        if (item.target.classList.contains('delbutton')) {
            let remID = item.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            records.splice(remID, 1);
            showrecords();
        }
    }

    function showrecords() {
        this.records = [];
        const index = 0;
        addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
        this.records.forEach(element => {
            let str = '<div class="entry">';
            str += `<div class="name"><p>' ${element.name}'</p></div>`;
            str += `<div class="phone"><p>' ${element.phone}'</p></div>`;
            str += `<div class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="${index}">deleted</a></div>`;
            addBookDiv.innerHTML += str;
        });
    }
    showrecords();
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <div class="firstDiv">
            <div class="secondDiv">
                <h1>Phone Book</h1>
                <input type="text" id="search" class="formFields">
                <input type="button" id="btnsearch" value="search">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="formFields">
                <input type="text" id="phone" class="formFields">
                <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add">
                <div class="addbook"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You seem to have asked 4-5 questions about this same program, it feels a little like you are just using stack overflow to avoid debugging. Perhaps it would be a better use of your time to go through some debugging tutorials.

Comment: @DBS I do not find any training on this and I do not know why no one guides

Comment: In `this.PhoneBookRecord = function(name, phone) {` what is `this`?

Comment: I updated my answer. Try the code snippet. Is that what you wanted to achieved?

Answer (score 2):

First you are using `this` keyword for `records` randomly and also you are cleaning the array (`records = []`) on every event so `for loop` is not working. Theirs no need to use `this` keyword here use `let` or `var` instead.

try this :

```
let ctrl = this;
function PhoneBookRecord(name, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}
ctrl.records = [];
function addToBook() {
    let isNull = name.value != '' && phone.value != '';
    if (isNull) {
        let obj = new PhoneBookRecord(name.value, phone.value);
        ctrl.records.push(obj);
        showrecords();
    }
}

function searchContact() {
    const result = ctrl.records.find((name) => name === selectInputsearch.value);
    if (!result === undefined) {
        console.log(result)
    } else {
        console.log("Contact not found")
    }
}

function removeEntry(item) {
    if (item.target.classList.contains('delbutton')) {
        let remID = item.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        ctrl.records.splice(remID, 1);
        showrecords();
    }
}

function showrecords() {
    const index = 0;
    addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
    ctrl.records.forEach(element => {
        let str = '<div class="entry">';
        str += `<div class="name"><p>' ${element.name}'</p></div>`;
        str += `<div class="phone"><p>' ${element.phone}'</p></div>`;
        str += `<div class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="${index}">deleted</a></div>`;
        addBookDiv.innerHTML += str;
    });
}
showrecords();
```

Comment: I did not want the presentation to be defined as a variable. I knew this
I want to mention this and my main problem is that the jess part does not work

Comment: ok then use use `this` keyword in every `records` you missing it in delete function and in add function. it will work as you are using sometimes `this` and sometime only `records` this cause js error of `undefined` so, `recors.forEach` you cant loop in a undefined value.

Comment: So I can not use this now until I want to define a variable?

Comment: no as `this` in function means the function it self you have to declar `this` in global to do that `var ctrl = this` then use `ctrl.records`. i am editing my answer check

Comment: Thank you my friend . I asked another question but no one helped me. Can you help me with that question as well?

Comment: share me link also check i have updated . if it help then accept my answer and up-vote it . thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071419/difficulty-finding-function-to-execute-code Question link

Comment: Can you help me with the question I left the link? If you want more details, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed version. The problem was that you initialized `records` as empty array in the beginning of each function. I just initialize the `records` in the global scope so every function will manipulate with that one. I have also fixed `searchContact()` function. The problem was that you filtered `records` as in is an array of strings, and it is an array of objects. You have to compare base on `name` property of each object. Check the changes below, and you can run the code snippet to see the result.

```js
let AddBtn = document.getElementById('Add');
    let search = document.getElementById('search');
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    let phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    let selectInputsearch = document.getElementById("search");
    let buttonsearch = document.getElementById("btnsearch");
    let addBookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook');
    
    let records = [];
    
    AddBtn.addEventListener("click", addToBook);
    addBookDiv.addEventListener("click", removeEntry);
    buttonsearch.addEventListener("click", searchContact);

    this.PhoneBookRecord = function(name, phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    function addToBook() {
        let isNull = name.value != '' && phone.value != '';
        if (isNull) {
            let obj = new PhoneBookRecord(name.value, phone.value);
            records.push(obj);
            showrecords();
        }

    }

    function searchContact() {
        const result = records.find((record) => record.name === selectInputsearch.value);
        if (result !== undefined) {
            console.log('Search result: ', result)
        } else {
            console.log("Contact not found")
        }
    }

    function removeEntry(item) {
        if (item.target.classList.contains('delbutton')) {
            let remID = item.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            records.splice(remID, 1);
            showrecords();
        }
    }

    function showrecords() {
        const index = 0;
        addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
        records.forEach(element => {
            let str = '<div class="entry">';
            str += `<div class="name"><p>' ${element.name}'</p></div>`;
            str += `<div class="phone"><p>' ${element.phone}'</p></div>`;
            str += `<div class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="${index}">deleted</a></div>`;
            addBookDiv.innerHTML += str;
        });
    }
    showrecords();
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="firstDiv">
            <div class="secondDiv">
                <h1>Phone Book</h1>
                <input type="text" id="search" class="formFields">
                <input type="button" id="btnsearch" value="search">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="formFields">
                <input type="text" id="phone" class="formFields">
                <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add">
                <div class="addbook"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend . I asked another question but no one helped me. Can you help me with that question as well?

Comment: What question is that? Also, consider upvoting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot I voted for your answer
Can you answer my other question? I leave the link, please help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071419/difficulty-finding-function-to-execute-code